# Что значит "отсутствие состояния"?

Tags: java, ооп

Читаю:

> Java SE 8 представляет собой единое наибольшее развитие языка Java в его истории. Относительно небольшое количество возможностей — лямбда-выражения, ссылки на методы и функциональные интерфейсы — объединены для получения модели программирования, которая сочетает объектно-ориентированный и функциональный стили. Под руководством Брайана Гетца (Brian Goetz) это слияние достигнуто таким образом, что поощряет лучшие практики — неизменность, **отсутствие состояния**, композиционность — при сохранении “чувства Java” — удобочитаемости, простоты, универсальности.

Что значит "отсутствие состояния"?

Comment: Отсутствие - диалектическая противоположность присутствию (или наличию). Чего тут непонятного? Или Вам не понятно понятие "состояние"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

В *объектно-ориентированном программировании* **объект** — это сущность, обладающая тремя признаками:

1. **Индивидуальность** (identity) — один **объект** можно отличить от другого.
2. **Поведение** (behaviour) — у **объекта** есть методы, которые меняют его состояние, и через которые он общается с внешним миром.
3. **Состояние** (state) — у **объекта** есть внутренние состояние, которое принадлежит объекту на протяжении его жизни, и от которого зависит поведение.

В *Функциональном программировании* **объектов** нет, но есть **функции**. И **функции** не имеют **состояния** — они чистое **поведение**

В *Java 8* были добавлены **лямбды** и другие вещи из функциональной парадигмы. **Лямбда** в  *функциональном программировании* — это анонимная **функция** и у нее нет состояния.

Вот об этом отсутствии **состояния** (как *функциональном программировании*) и идет речь.

Answer (score 17):

Это плохой перевод термина *stateless*, то есть объекта который не имеет состояния:

> Stateless object is an instance of a class without instance fields (instance variables). The class may have fields, but they are compile-time constants (static final).

переводя на общедоступный русский язык, это объект который не имеет полей/переменных описывающих его внутреннее состояние. Точнее объект может иметь поля, но это переменные типа `static final`, то есть неизменяемые.

**Update**

> зачем вообще нужны такие объекты и почему это считается хорошей практикой?

Все зависит от контекста. Есть ситуации, когда это хорошая практика. Для понятности приведу пример из обычной жизни:

1. Каждое утро вы садитесь с свою машину: в машине под себя любимого уже все настроено - любимая радиостанция, положение руля, кресел, зеркал, бутылочка с водичкой - то есть ваша машина в данном случае объект *stateful*, объект, который помнит свое состояние.
2. Противоположное состояние: вы берете машину напрокат - в прокатной компании из машины удаляется весь *state* наработанный предыдущим арендатором - машина моется, чистится, положение кресел, зеркал, магнитолы, сбрасываются в состояние *default*, выкидываются из машины лишние вещи то есть машина превращается в *stateless* и это хорошо. Обратим внимание, что прокатная компания добивается некоего стандартного состояния машины одинакового для всего своего автопарка (то есть *state* будет `static final` - одинаковый для всех экземпляров класса). Ты садишься в машину и все настраиваешь под себя, ты не думаешь о предыдущем состоянии машины.

Вот это и есть контекст: если нам по логике, всегда нужен объект в стандартизированном состоянии - это работает подход *stateless*, если же логика требует чтобы мы каждый раз использовали предыдущее состояние - это подход *stateful*

Comment: Не обязательно static, достаточно final чтобы не быть состоянием.

Comment: Неправда. Требуется, чтобы переменные были константами уже в момент компиляции, что дается только `final static`, простой `final` - не прокатит

Comment: Хм, но зачем в таком случае вообще нужны такие объекты и почему это считается хорошей практикой?

Comment: Обновил. См. ответ

Comment: *"Ты садишься в машину и все настраиваешь под себя"* - для описанного вами stateless это невозможно. Это скорее описание работы паттерна "фабрика" чем stateless.

Comment: Почему? Настройка делается параметрами вызова stateless объекта..

Comment: @BarmaleysupportsMonica, у вызова объекта нет параметров. Параметры есть при создании объекта – это салон настраивает для всех.

Answer (score 9):

Чтобы понять разницу между объектами имеющими состояние и нет, приведу пример:

```
private static class Stateless {
    public String addPrefix(String prefix, String str) {
        return prefix + str;
    }
}

private static class Stateful {
    private String prefix = "prefix";

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public String addPrefix(String str) {
        return prefix + str;
    }
}
```

Класс `Stateless` не имеет внутреннего состояния, т.к. у него отсутствуют нестатические поля.
А `Stateful`, напротив, имеет состояние, т.к. у него есть поле `prefix`, которое к тому же можно изменять. Изменение нестатических полей объекта называется *изменением состояния*.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, правильный термин — не "statable", а "stateful". Например: [Stateless vs Stateful - I could use some concrete information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329618/stateless-vs-stateful-i-could-use-some-concrete-information)